# removing object from list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to remove an object list item in javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var eventObjs = [];
    var idVal = 0;
    $("#addItem").click(function () {
        eventObjs.push([{ title: 'test', personId: idVal }]);
        idVal += 1;
    });

    $("#removeItem").click(function () {
        idVal -= 1;
        eventObjs = eventObjs
            .filter(function (el) {
            return el.personId !== (idVal - 1);
        });
        $("#arrVal").html(eventObjs.length);       
    });
});
```

**Fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/webdad3/51vbzne1/2/

I can add my elements just fine.  But when I try to remove them.  Nothing works.  Where am I going wrong?

I got the code to remove items from the array from an example.  Maybe the question isn't what am I doing wrong with the above, but what do I need to do to remove item from my list?

Comment: *"But when I try to remove them..."* The DOM elements, or the entries in your `eventObj` array? *"Nothing works. Where am I going wrong?"* If you're talking about DOM elements, show us what you tried -- there's nothing in the above that's trying to remove DOM elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your filter condition is wrong.

Here is the correct version: http://jsfiddle.net/51vbzne1/3/

```
    eventObjs = eventObjs.filter(function (el) {
        return el.personId <= idVal;
    });
```

**Explanation**: you should filter to check that every `personId` is lower than the current `idVal`. Since you are doing the `idVal -= 1` before filtering, you need to use `<=`.

Or if you want to remove a specific item. Use splice, eg: `eventObjs.splice(idVal, 1);`

Comment: lets say for arguments sake that I had to pass in the idVal.  How would you change it then?

Comment: If so. You should use the splice function. `eventObjs.splice(idVal, 1);` or `eventObjs.splice(idVal-1, 1);`

Comment: I thought I read that splice() wouldn't work on an associative array?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var eventObjs = [];
    var idVal = 0;
    $("#addItem").click(function () {
        eventObjs.push([{
            title: 'test', personId: idVal
        }]);
        idVal += 1;

        alert(eventObjs.length);
    });

    $("#removeItem").click(function () {
        eventObjs.splice(-1);
        idVal = idVal -1;
        alert(idVal);
    });
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/51vbzne1/5/

Comment: what if I'm passing in the idVal and it isn't always -1 like in my example?  Lets say it was the middle element?

Comment: `eventObjs.splice(idVal, 1);`

Comment: This would also be my solution, you can easily pass in the index and splice away :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Replace `eventObjs.push([{ title: 'test', personId: idVal
   }]);` with `eventObjs.push({ title: 'test', personId: idVal });`. Now you have something like `[[{title: 'test1'}], [{title: 'test2'}]]`, instead of `[{title: 'test1'}, {title: 'test2'}]`
2. Replace `return el.personId !== (idVal - 1);` with `return
   el.personId !== idVal;`

Comment: Using a filter to remove a single element is not the best solution :/.